# Cutting one raster with another using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

I'm trying to calculate runoff coefficient with some Vegetation Indexes , but I get the error:

> ImageCollection.reduce: Error in map(ID=LC08_001004_20200609):
>
> Image.eq: Parameter 'image1' is required.

Below is the script code, something is wrong in NDVI part:

```js
//////  PARTE DE CÁLCULO DO COEFICIENTE DE ESCOAMENTO //////
////Coleções e limites
var imagem = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
.filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-12-01');

var regioes = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/et-brasil/assets/ANA_project/geometries/regioes_br_simplified");
var area_estudo = regioes.filterMetadata('NM_REGIAO','equals','Sul');

// Coleção MapBiomas
var MapBiomas_imagem = (ee.Image('projects/mapbiomas-workspace/public/collection5/mapbiomas_collection50_integration_v1'));
var bandas = MapBiomas_imagem.bandNames();

var MapBiomas_colecao = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(bandas.map(function(name){
  
  var Band_name = ee.String(name);
  var year_image = ee.Number.parse(Band_name.replace('classification_',''));
  return MapBiomas_imagem.select(Band_name)
                  .rename('classification')
                  .set('year',year_image)
                  .set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(year_image,1,1).millis());
}));

var Parametros_MapBiomas = {"min": 0, "max": 33,
        "palette": "129912,1f4423,006400,32cd32,687537,935132," +
                   "bbfcac,45c2a5,b8af4f,968c46,#ff8c00,bdb768," +
                   "ffffb2,ffd966,e974ed,d5a68d,c59ff4,c27ba0,e787f8,f3b4f1,fff3bf," +
                   "ea9999,dd7e6b,aa0000,af2a2a,ff99ff," +
                   "0000ff,29eee4," +
                   "d5d5e5"};  

Map.addLayer(MapBiomas_colecao, Parametros_MapBiomas,'Coleção MapBiomas');

var col_areas_urbanas = MapBiomas_colecao.map(function(image){
  var valor_urbano = image.updateMask(image.eq(24));
  return valor_urbano.eq(24).rename('urban').set('system:time_start',image.get('system:time_start'))});

//// NDVI
var ndvi = imagem.map(function(image) {
  var index = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5','SR_B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(index).select('NDVI');
});

var col_ndvi = ndvi.map(function (image){
  var time_start = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
  var year = time_start.get('year');
  var area_urbana_ano = col_areas_urbanas.filterMetadata('year','equals', year).first();
  var imagem_update = image.updateMask(area_urbana_ano.eq(1));
  return imagem_update.set('system:time_start',time_start.millis());
});

Map.addLayer(col_ndvi, {palette: ['white','red']}); /// apenas para testar se o NDVI está cortando

//// NDBI
var ndbi = imagem.map(function(image) {
  var index = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B6','SR_B5']).rename('NDBI');
  return image.addBands(index).select('NDBI');
});

//// Build Up
var build_up = imagem.map(function(image) {
  var index = image.expression(
    '(ndbi*ndbi)-(ndvi*ndvi)',{
      'ndbi':ndbi,
      'ndvi': ndvi
  }).rename('BU');
  return image.addBands(index).select('BU');
});

//// Classificação por mascaras
var not_veg_mask = col_ndvi.reduce(ee.Reducer.max()).gte(0.1).lt(0.3); // variável urbana NDVI
// var not_veg_mask = ndbi.reduce(ee.Reducer.max()).gte(0.0).lt(0.1); // variável urbana NDBI
// var not_veg_mask = build_up.reduce(ee.Reducer.max()).gte(-0.1).lt(0.0); // variável urbana BUILD UP
var not_veg_mask = not_veg_mask.updateMask(not_veg_mask).rename('Area_Impermeavel');

var vegetacao_mask = col_ndvi.reduce(ee.Reducer.max()).gte(0.3); // variável vegetação NDVI
// var vegetacao_mask = ndbi.reduce(ee.Reducer.max()).lt(-0.35); // variável vegetação NDBI
// var vegetacao_mask = build_up.reduce(ee.Reducer.max()).lt(-0.5); // variável vegetação BU
var vegetacao_mask = vegetacao_mask.updateMask(vegetacao_mask).rename('Vegetacao');

var join_mascaras = not_veg_mask.addBands(vegetacao_mask);

var area_mascara = join_mascaras.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

var area_de_mascara = area_mascara.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: area_estudo,
  scale: 250,
  maxPixels: 1e13});
  
var area_total_mascara = ee.Number(area_de_mascara);
print('Área total Mascara', area_total_mascara);

//// Gráfico
var a = ee.Array(area_de_mascara.get('Area_Impermeavel'));
var b = ee.Array(area_de_mascara.get('Vegetacao'));
var lista = ee.List([a,b]);
var Nomes = ee.List(['Area_Impermeavel','Vegetacao']);

var grafico_area_feature = ui.Chart.array.values(lista,0, Nomes)
.setChartType('PieChart')
.setOptions(
  {width:250,
  height: 350,
  title: 'Area por Classe (metros)',
  is3d: true,
  colors:['blue','green']
  });
print(grafico_area_feature);

//// Cálculo Coeficiente Tucci (0,27 + 0,72*Ai)
var area_imperm = ee.Number(area_de_mascara.get('Area_Impermeavel'));
var area_vegeta = ee.Number(area_de_mascara.get('Vegetacao'));
var area_total = area_imperm.add(area_vegeta);

var eq_Tucci_pt1 = ee.Number(area_de_mascara.get('Area_Impermeavel'))
    .divide(area_total)
    .multiply(0.72);

var coef_sup_Tucci = eq_Tucci_pt1.add(0.27);
print('Coeficiente Escoamento Superficial', coef_sup_Tucci);

//// Cálculo Coef Média Ponderada 
var med_imperm = area_imperm.divide(area_total).multiply(0.95); /// valor padrão p/ area imperm
var med_vegeta = area_vegeta.divide(area_total).multiply(0.25); /// valor padrão p/ area vegeta

var coef_med = med_imperm.add(med_vegeta);
print('Coeficiente Média', coef_med);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/cdd2292ac4f3a6628eba90679c1e72fe

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown in the lines that you define `col_ndvi`. Specifically, `col_areas_urbanas` has no property named 'year', so `area_urbana_ano` is assiged a `null` in the following line:

```
var area_urbana_ano = col_areas_urbanas.filterMetadata('year','equals', year).first();
```

It appears that you forgot to copy all the properties from the original image collection `MapBiomas_colecao`. Following your code, this can be done in a 'brute force' approach by adding a 'year' property to the returned image:

```
var col_areas_urbanas = MapBiomas_colecao.map(function(image){
  var valor_urbano = image.updateMask(image.eq(24));
  return valor_urbano.eq(24).rename('urban')
    .set('system:time_start',image.get('system:time_start'))
    .set('year', image.get('year'))});
```

Alternatively, you could use `.copyProperties`:

```
var col_areas_urbanas = MapBiomas_colecao.map(function(image){
  var valor_urbano = image.updateMask(image.eq(24));
  return valor_urbano.eq(24).rename('urban').copyProperties(image)});
```

---

Even if you make this edit, your code will throw an error at the following line:

```
var area_urbana_ano = col_areas_urbanas.filterMetadata('year','equals', year).first();
```

This is because your image collection `ndvi` has been filtered for only images from 2020 (line 1), yet `col_areas_urbanas` only contains images with a 'year' property from 1985 to 2019. Otherwise, your code will run without being a thrown an error. You can show this by hard-coding `year` with someinthg arbitrary. For example, if you make the change

```
var area_urbana_ano = col_areas_urbanas.filterMetadata('year','equals', 2019).first();
```

your code will run.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!